# I am not getting output when submitting a Form button PHP email code is not giving me result

Tags: php, html, mail-form

I was trying to write contact form using HTML & PHP, it was working fine when I was testing the code with `input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"`

But while using div & button class:"" it's not working for me.

Can someone help me?

MY PHP CODE

```
<? php 

       if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{

        $to = "example@gmail.com";

        $from = $_POST['email'];

      $name = $_POST['name'];

      $email = $_POST['email'];

      $phone =$_POST['phone'];  

      $subject = "Enquiry From".$name;

      $subject2 = "Copy of your Enquiry";

      $message = $name . " " . "wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'] ."Contact Details:" . "\n\n" .$_POST['email'] . $_POST['phone'];

    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 

echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";

}
?>
```

===========================

HTML FORM CODE

```
<div class="container-contact100">

    <div class="wrap-contact100">
        <form class="contact100-form validate-form" action="mail.php" method="post">
            <span class="contact100-form-title">
                Feel free to reach us
            </span>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Please enter your name">
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Please enter your email: e@a.x">
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Please enter your phone">
                <input class="input100" type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Please enter your Subject">
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Please enter your message">
                <textarea class="input100" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="contact100-form-btn" type="submit">
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o m-r-6" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Send
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>
```

Comment: You didn't say *what* is not working. "Not working" doesn't really mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> if(isset($_POST['email']))

Why?
You don’t have any element whose name is submit.
You repeated type=“submit” twice